# How can I have two POST requests in the same view without getting MultiValueDictKeyError?

Tags: python, html, django

my view originally worked as a search engine (in which the POST request returns the search results) but I added a function so that the user can 'favorite' any item that's returned so that it'll be added to their profile. However, since I have two different post requests, the second request (which is the one to favorite the item) returns MultiValueDictKeyError since it's still referencing the first post request. How can I make my view take both different requests?

This is the view code (def anime is the one not working):

```
def search(request):
   animes = []

   if request.method == 'POST':
       animes_url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q={}&limit=6&page=1'
       
       search_params = {
           'animes' : 'title',
           'q' : request.POST['search']
           
           }

       r = requests.get(animes_url, params=search_params)
       results = r.json()
       
       results = results['results']
       
       
       if len(results):
           for result in results:
               animes_data = {
                   'Id' : result["mal_id"],
                   'Title' : result["title"],
                   'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
                   'Image' : result["image_url"]
               }
               animes.append(animes_data)
       else:
           message = print("No results found")

       for item in animes:
           print(item)
    
   context = {
   'animes' : animes
   }
       
   return render(request,'search.html', context)

def anime(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       anime_id = request.POST.get("anime_id")
       anime = Anime.objects.get(id = anime_id)
       request.user.profile.animes.add(anime)
       messages.success(request,(f'{anime} added to wishlist.'))
       return redirect ('/search')
   animes = Anime.objects.all()
   
   return render(request = request, template_name="search.html")
```

This is the html:

```
<body>
 

 <div class = "container">
   <div class = "text-center container">
     <br>
     <h2 class = "text-center">Search for your favorite animes</h2> 
     <br>
     <form action='search' method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." class = "text-center">
       <button type="submit" class = "btn-danger btn-sm">Search</button>

   </div> 
   </form>
   
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   {% if animes %}
   {% for anime in animes %}
   <form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <section>
       <div class=row>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
         <div class="card">
           
           <div class="card-body text-center">
             <p class="card-title"> <b>{{anime.Title}}</b></p>
             <hr>
             <p class="card-text">Episodes: <b>{{anime.Episodes}}</b></p>
             
             <img src = {{anime.Image}} />
             
           </div>
         </div>
     </section>
     <input type="hidden" value="{{anime.Id}}" name="anime_id">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size:18px; border-radius: 50%">★</button>
                                       
   </form>

       
       
   </div>
     
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
 {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
</body>
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
   list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'search'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/core/views.py", line 31, in search
   'q' : request.POST['search']
 File "/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
   raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'search'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `request.POST.get('search',None)` not `request.POST['search']` in your search_params dict

```
  search_params = {
       'animes' : 'title',
       'q' : request.POST.get('search',None)   
  }
```

Comment: If I write it like that it returns: KeyError at /search 'results'

Comment: do r.json() have a key 'result' ?

Comment: to debug add ```print(vars(result))``` in the line before the error occurs?

Comment: it returns TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Comment: the result is what I was getting before in the search engine but it still doesn't work with the second post request since it returns that error when I try to post there. I'm not sure how this is supposed to help, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: great, but when you print the result can you see a key "result" somewhere in it?

Comment: no, but that's because I am returning the dictionary that's inside the key 'result' so that's why I don't see it because basically the api returns a dictionary with nested dictionaries and I need the one inside the 'result' one

Comment: that's the exact reason why you are getting ```KeyError at /search 'results' ```, because you are passing a key that does not exist, you got it?

Comment: I understand but how can I fix it when it comes to the second post request? If I don't change the code like you suggested, it does get the anime_id I need but it returns the MultiValueDictKeyError but if I change it, it returns this... maybe the answer lies somewhere else

Comment: What you mean by second post, that's not clear to me..

Comment: The issue is with the def anime post request, not with the search one. The search post request works either way but the anime one does not